# pandas merge columns and adding the original column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a Dataframe with value predictions.

The first column is for the exact value and each new column is a week in the future. For each week a new row is added.
As a result, I have the following example table:

```
Index W1  W2  W3  W4
1.     5   7   4   9
2.     8   7  10  11
```

and so on.

I want the values to all be in a single row and I want the other rows to be the number of weeks ahead (in my case exactly the column index of the value).

My table should look like this:

```
Index Value Week
1.        5    1
2.        7    2
3.        4    3 
4.        9    4
5.        8    1
6.        7    2 
7.       10    3
8.       11    4
```

I am working with python and have just declared the dataframe. How can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a variation on `melt`:

```
(df.melt(id_vars='Index', value_name='Value')
   .assign(Week=lambda d: d['variable'].str[1:].astype(int))
   .drop(columns='variable')
   .sort_values('Index')
)
```

output:

```
   Index  Value  Week
0    1.0      5     1
2    1.0      7     2
4    1.0      4     3
6    1.0      9     4
1    2.0      8     1
3    2.0      7     2
5    2.0     10     3
7    2.0     11     4
```

Answer (score 1):

First `rename` columns names with cast to integers and remove `W` and then reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with some data cleaning by [`Series.droplevel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.droplevel.html), [`Series.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename_axis.html) and [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
df = (df.rename(columns= lambda x: int(x.replace('W','')))
        .stack()
        .droplevel(0)
        .rename_axis('Week')
        .reset_index(name='Value'))
print (df)
   Week  Value
0     1      5
1     2      7
2     3      4
3     4      9
4     1      8
5     2      7
6     3     10
7     4     11
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use `stack`:

```
df.columns = [c.strip('W') for c in df.columns]
res = (df.set_index('Index').stack().droplevel(level=0).reset_index()).rename(columns = {0:'Value'})
```

prints:

```
  index  Value
0     1      5
1     2      7
2     3      4
3     4      9
4     1      8
5     2      7
6     3     10
7     4     11
```